# How to use std::auto_ptr as a parameter of function?

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

I need to use RAII idiom, am I doing it right ?:

```
std::auto_ptr<std::vector<string>> MyFunction1()
{
   std::auto_ptr<std::vector<string>> arrayOfStrings;

   MyFunction2(arrayOfStrings); // work with arrayOfStrings

   return arrayOfStrings;
}

void MyFunction2(std::auto_ptr<std::vector<string>> array)
{
   auto_ptr<string> str;
   *str = "foo string";
   array.push_back(str)
}
```

Or maybe shoudl I free the memory by myself instead of using smart pointers ? If so, how to do that ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a note: `std::auto_ptr` is now deprecated. It tried to implement move semantics before move semantics existed. Take a look at `std::unique_ptr`, which does it properly.

Comment: Take a look at `std::shared_ptr`, that should solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't use pointers, not even smart ones in this case:

```
std::vector<string> MyFunction1()
{
   std::vector<string> arrayOfStrings;
   MyFunction2(arrayOfStrings); // work with arrayOfStrings
   return arrayOfStrings;
}

void MyFunction2(std::vector<string> &array)
{
   array.push_back("foo string");
}
```

The compiler will surely optimize the return value copy away, applying an optimization called [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), so you shouldn't worry about that. Using pointers, in this case, to avoid copying will probably end up being more inefficient and tedious to work with, compared to using objects allocated on the stack and relying on this optimization.

Otherwise, consider using `std::unique_ptr` as @templatetypedef mentions. Avoid pointers whenever you can.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a function that takes a `std::auto_ptr` by value, then whatever `std::auto_ptr` that you pass into that function will relinquish control of the resource and hand it off to the function that it calls.  As a result, when the function returns, the original `std::auto_ptr` will no longer point to the resource it originally pointed to.  As a result, you can think of taking in a `std::auto_ptr` by value as saying "I am going to take your resource away from you and do something with it."

To fix this, consider making your function take the `std::auto_ptr` by reference, which doesn't steal the reference.

But that said, you should stop using `std::auto_ptr` and start using `std::unique_ptr` instead.  `std::unique_ptr` is a much safer and more sane replacement for `std::auto_ptr`.  You can't pass `std::unique_ptr` by value without explicitly using `std::move` to relinquish control of the resource, and there aren't any "gotcha!"-style surprises with it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 but missed one important aspect: OP never initialised the pointers.